# Error connecting to SQLite database in Windows Phone 8.1 application

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing application by using Xamarin Forms. I need database so I install `sqlite-net-pcl` by Frank A.Krueger via NuGet package manager. I try to get connection in PCL project:

```
ISQLiteHelper sqlLiteHelper = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteHelper>();
string pathToDatabaseFile = sqlLiteHelper.GetLocalDatabaseFilePath(databaseFilename);
this.database = new SQLiteConnection(pathToDatabaseFile);
```

But I got an exception.

> "Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

I followed by some answers and download and installed `sqlite-wp81-winrt-3180000.vsix` Than I added the following references into my WinPhone 8.1 project: Reference Manager -> Windows Phone 8.1 -> Extensions -> SQLite for Windows 8.1 But it did not help me. I got the same error.

I changed my target platform to x86. For Any CPU I get an error:

> "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs,
>   Version=12.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor
>   architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done
>   through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures
>   supported by the SDK: "x86, ARM". App1.WinPhone

[image: Reference manager screenshot]

[image: NuGet screenshot]

[image]

I got that error if I change my target platform to x64 like my PC has.

> "X64" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs,
>   Version=12.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor
>   architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done
>   through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures
>   supported by the SDK: "x86, ARM". App1.WinPhone
>
> "X64" is not supported by the referenced SDK "SQLite.WP81,
>   Version=3.18.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor
>   architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done
>   through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures
>   supported by the SDK: "x86, ARM". App1.WinPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** You can use `SQLite.Net-PCL` by Oustein Krog, Frank Krueger, Tim Heuer instead of `sqlite-net-pcl`.

The creation of collection will look like this one:

```
this.database = new SQLiteConnection(databaseFilename);
```